# Using session values in socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am doing login operations with loginControl function on my controller page

source;

```
const LoginControl = (req, res) => {

    db.query("SELECT * FROM users", (error, result) => {

        if (error) throw error;


        const username = req.body.name;
        const userpassword = req.body.password;

        result.forEach(element => {


            if (username == element.username &&userpassword==element.password) {
                req.session.username = username;
                req.session.password = userpassword;

                res.redirect("/anasayfa");
                return;


            }
            res.render("login");

        });
    });
}
module.exports = { LoginControl };
```

I want to use the session username value here in the socket codes in app.js.

app.js page sources:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Bir istemci bağlandı');


  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Bir istemci ayrıldı');
  });

  socket.on('messageFromClient', (data) => {

    const message = data.message;
    const user = data.user;

    if (message != "" && user != "") {
      db.query("INSERT INTO messages (text,sender) VALUES (?,?)", [message, "user"], (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("veri eklendi");

      });

    }
    console.log("Boş mesaj gönderilemez");


  });


  socket.on('messageFromClient', (data) => {
    console.log('İstemciden gelen mesaj:', data);
    io.emit('messageFromServer', data);
  });
});
```

here "const user = data.user;" I will print the session.username value here, then I should write it where it says "user" in the database query and save it to the database.

I tried using handshake.query but I couldn't get the session value from the controller page in my app.js page. I wrote to chatgpt and bard for a solution, but their methods caused more errors.